# Outputs dir is ignored by UP-TO-DATE check

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I created plugin that is supposed to have Input on Output directory, to run when any of these two changes. When I defined it in build.gradle for single task, it worked fine. When defined in Java by Gradle API, only directory defined as Inputs triggers the re-run of task.

```
 task.getInputs().dir(target.file("./src/main/res/values/"));
 task.getOutputs().dir(target.file("./inputs/"));
```

Tried setting `setDidWork(true);` but that did not help. And any change in output does not trigger change in UP-TO-DATE status of this task.

Comment: I had faced with the similar problem and it went away after updating gradle from 3.2 to 3.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used annotations on task class, that are called in correct time and work.

```
@OutputDirectory
public File getOutputDir() {
    return  getProject().getRootProject().file(extension.getOutputPath());
}

@InputDirectory
public File getInputsDir() {
    return  getProject().getRootProject().file(extension.getPath());
}
```